# Will uninstalling and reinstalling a certain game over time slow down it's performance?

Tags: maplestory

I've had my computer for about 4 years now and one of the first games I downloaded when I first got it was Maplestory. I usually play it for about a month and then uninstall it but I do come back to it every so often just to see what it's like. Now I don't know if the game itself has grown so much that my pc can't keep up with the game's demands or if the slowed performance in the game is because I've uninstalled and reinstalled it so many times. I used to play the game with no stutters and it ran smoothly. As of now I have to turn off skill affects and if there are too many enemies on the screen, the game will stutter when I attack. I'm not  sure what's going on here. I think it might be with the remnants of the game being searched through alongside the actual installed files being searched through too.

Comment: There's too many variables to this, uninstalling/reinstalling software in general isn't good for your hard drive, so you'll have other problems to deal with besides game slowdown. as for the game slowdown point, it could very well they are keeping the game updated with modern tech, so you need to update as well. I haven't played Maplestory in a while, but I do remember it not being demanding *at all*, so if you are struggling, it may be worth looking into new hardware.

Comment: I played Maplestory a decade ago, and it was a buggy mess then. Just for fun, I recently downloaded MS to see what kind of updates had happened in the years since I left... I found a lot of the exact same bugs that had existed for years. Normally I'd blame your hardware, but in this specific case, I would not be surprised if MS is just getting too bloated to work well. It seems the devs just add new layers of complexity without ever fixing the older layers.

Comment: It's very unlikely that uninstalling and reinstalling the game specifically would cause performance issues. As @Rapitor says, you can wear down your hard drive by frequently uninstalling/reinstalling anything, but I doubt that any leftover files from previous installs will ever cause you any issues.

Comment: The performance degradation of Maplestory is completely unrelated to your reinstallation habits. The dev team is widely known to be sloppy, especially in the GMS localization.

Comment: @MageXy Yea, I think the complexity is the issue. Also, I've done a lot of random crap to my computer which has a 1.5 Ghz AMD a4-5000, nothing to boast about. Maplestory is tacking so much on. And you're right, I don't think they are optimizing it very well. It used to be that pulling up quest menu took forever. Idk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing/Uninstalling a game should not affect it's performance.

If your computer is older, I'd suggest pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ESCAPE, that will give you an idea of what is taking your computer ressources and can help you single out the problem that is slowing down your Maplestory experience.

You probably have something running in the background that takes ressources away. I really wonder what tho, because I'm pretty sure MapleStory could run on about anything, including my toaster.

Comment: Thanks! I had a bunch of random background processes and ended them all. The game still plays like a potato but a lot less of a potato than before.

Comment: Would be a good idea for you to track down what those processes are. Do you need them? Are they something you use? If you can't find anything on it, better not touch it.